# Clarification on computation of eigenvectors using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvector

I am reviewing some linear algebra and working through some implementations in Python. I am working through a problem related to finding eigenvectors of a matrix `A`.

```
A = [[ 1, 2,-2], 
     [-2, 5,-2], 
     [-6, 6,-3]]
```

When I solve this problem by hand, I get eigenvalues 3 and -3, with 3 having a multiplicity of 2. My eigenvectors are `[[1/3], [1/3], [1]], [[1], [1], [0]], [[-1], [0], [1]]`.

Trying my implementation in NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
A = [[ 1, 2, -2], 
     [-2, 5, -2], 
     [-6, 6, -3]]
np.linalg.eig(A)
```

which gives the output

```
(array([ 3., -3.,  3.]), array([[ 0.53452248, -0.30151134, -0.05332571],
                                [-0.26726124, -0.30151134, -0.73225996],
                                [-0.80178373, -0.90453403, -0.67893425]]))
```

The eigenvalues are what I would expect, but the eigenvectors are confusing to me. From what I've read, I understand they are the columns and they are normalized, i.e., `norm(e1) = 1`. Also, numerically they seem to be correct in the sense they satisfy the Ax = lambda*x equation.

Furthermore, when I do the implementation in SymPy, I get the expected result.

```
from sympy.matrices import Matrix, eye, zeros, ones, diag, GramSchmidt
A = Matrix([[ 1, 2, -2], 
            [-2, 5, -2], 
            [-6, 6, -3]])
A.eigenvects()
```

Output:

```
[(-3, 1, [Matrix([
[1/3],
[1/3],
[  1]])]), (3, 2, [Matrix([
[1],
[1],
[0]]), Matrix([
[-1],
[ 0],
[ 1]])])]
```

Can anyone shed some light on the differences and what's going on with NumPy? Is it solving numerically and these aren't truly eigenvectors but they seem to be in the sense they satisfy the conditions within a certain level of numerical precision? Thank you.

Comment: If `x` satisfies the eigenvector equation, `c*x` also satisfies the equation for any scalar `c`.

Answer (score 4):

Here, the eigenvalue 3 has geometric multiplicity 2 (the rank of the matrix (*A* - 3 *I*) is 1) and there are infinitely many ways to choose the two basis vectors (eigenvectors) for this eigenspace.

In the case of [normal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) *A*, `numpy.linalg.eig` will return an array of row eigenvectors forming a set of orthonormal bases of the whole space, and in computing practice the eigenvectors are unique up to permutations and the orientation (sign) in each column.  In the non-normal case (as is here) there's no unique choice, only a unique partition of the whole space into sub(eigen)spaces associated with each eigenvalue.

You can consider the output eigenvectors for the eigenvalue 3 (namely, the 0th and 2nd columns in the returned eigenvector array) an arbitrary set of bases satisfying the eigenvalue equation.

The implementation should be a wrapper of the underlying [`?GEEV`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack95/lug95/node260.html) function of the LAPACK API. Apart from matching the order of eigenvalues (which is ordered as conjugate pairs), the only constraint on the output eigenvectors seems

> Each eigenvector is scaled so that the Euclidean norm is 1 and the largest component is real.

So there's still lots of arbitrariness and I wouldn't count on a particular output.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, which is the meaning intended here.

Comment: None taken .. Off to add a few links